# Search device using MAC address

Tags: arp

I want to check presence of a device in network. The IP address of device keeps on changing. Is there any way I can search device through MAC address.
Through ARP I can ping the device but as IP keep on changing, I am thinking get device through MAC address.

Is there any mechanism to search device through MAC.

Comment: Yes arp_send can scan and resolve arp cache but I am not working in Linux so can not use...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure what you tried so far.

```
 arp -s < IP address > < MAC address >
```

There is an interesting article published by Microsoft
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961394.aspx

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use a tool called arp-scan.